# Postgres error: fatal role "username" does not exist

Tags: qgis, postgresql, command-line

I by mistake installed PostgreSQL twice, uninstalled one, and now I am trying to create a new PostGIS connection in QGIS but receive the following error when testing the connection:

```
fatal role "username" does not exist.
```

In the command line, when I run

```
sudo -u user psql user
sudo: unknown user: user
```

PostgreSQL is running however on Port 5432.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried creating the user in pgAdmin?

Comment: Default admin is postgres. Did you try ?

Comment: I don't know how to log out of my current connection

Comment: You might try posting this question over at the dba site  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql

Comment: If you installed postgres twice, the second will run on a different port. Evene after deinstallation of the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new user, this works for me:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -s <desired_user_name>
```

Then you can

```
psql <desired_user_name>
```

Comment: I think it should be `sudo -u postgres createuser -s <desired_user_name>`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working in linux command line, try:

```
sudo su postgres
```

Or if you think your admin username is 'psql', just replace 'postgres' with 'psql'.